# Powershell get top parent folder

Tags: powershell

My ultimate goal is to get a list of top level folders (for a given path) where a file has been modified in the last day.

There are probably a lot of ways to do this. The place where I am having a problem is getting the top level folder only.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\data\*" -recurse | 
where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} |  
where-object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | 
Foreach-Object { $_.DirectoryName} | 
sort -unique
```

It gets all the directories though, not just the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

```
$dirs = dir "sometoplevelpath" |?{ $_.PsIsContainer }
$oneDayAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$dirs |?{ dir $_ -Recurse |?{!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $oneDayAgo } | select -first 1 }
```

Comment: That works Great.  Thanks.  Thanks to Chris too as that was one way he mentioned of doing it.

Comment: You're welcome.  If it solved your problem and worked great, consider upvoting the answer and/or marking it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the list of folders that you end up with and compare their full path without their name and see if it matches the directory that contains the folders you're interested in:

```
$folders | Where-Object {$_.FullName.Replace($_.Name,"") -eq $superDirectory}
```

Where $superdDirectory is the name of the directory that contains the "top level directories".  In this case, that sounds like "C:\".

You could also investigate the PSParentPath property.

Another method would be to make a list of potential backup folders first:

```
$targetFolders = Get-Item -Path "C:\data*" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

And then go through that list to see if they have any items that need backing up, taking action if they do.

```
$targetFolders | % {
    $folderItems = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | ? {.... use your filter here}
    if (($folderItems | Measure-Object).Count -gt 0){
        #Backup the folder, or add $_.FullName to the list of folders that should be backed up.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think last method you list will work.  I'm not sure what the first method is doing. It didn't seem to work.  My root directory is "c:\data" so I want folders that are directly below that.  That isn't what I got when I tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `-recurse`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\data*" | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)} | where-object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | Foreach-Object {$_.DirectoryName} | sort -unique
```

I also changed the `$.` to `$_.`.  See if this works.  I got it to give me only the top level directory names, but I don't have anything I can run as a pattern like `"c\data*"`

Comment: With the recurse and without the last 2 pipes, I get a bunch of files. When I add in the last 2 pipes, I get nothing.

Comment: If I get rid of the last condition and just list {$_.FullName.Replace($_.Name,"")}, I get the whole path (like c:\data\firefox\cache, so the condition will never be met of it matching c:\data unless it is a file in the c:\data root.

Comment: What I really need is anything after the c:\data\ to the next "\".  Not sure how to do that.  Basically, all the top level folders under c:\data.